# Opensaml - tamper saml response for testing

Tags: security, saml, opensaml

I need to test a service provider implementation and we are using opensaml. I want to alter a given saml response and do permutation of assertion s elements , inject more assertion and so on. I was able to cover some cases by using opensaml method itself like getassertions on saml response object. But i see that if i want to move elements around or do more complex manipulation i would need to play with the respone as dom document . Does opensaml provide such funcutionality?  If not how i can create an encoded response from the modified xml?.thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maniupulate the XML in a way that does not conform to the SAML standard then you can not use OpenSAML, "move elements around" implies this. In this case I would try to manually craft the XML and then write a manual encoder based on information in the SAML spec.

Comment: And just to point out, some elements *cannot* just be moved around. SAML spec isn't the easiest thing to read, and it doesn't seem like there is ordering of elements, but there is in some cases. This is why it's *generally* better to use a tried and tested framework when building an integration rather than rolling your own from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to do that for testing purpose.

Comment: Anyway once valid response is created by OpenSaml in my mock (Response object) I found a getDom() function which allows me then to manipulate the message. Yes then I used my encoder to encode it.

Comment: In this example I do:

legitimateUserSAMLResponse.getAssertions().clear();
legitimateUserSAMLResponse.getAssertions().add(Assertion1);
legitimateUserSAMLResponse.getAssertions().add(Assertion2);

org.w3c.dom.Element dom = legitimateUserSAMLResponse.getDOM();

Element asse = (Element) dom.getElementsByTagName("saml2:Assertion").item(0); // java.lang.NullPointerException
Element asse2 = (Element) dom.getElementsByTagName("saml2:Assertion").item(1);
org.w3c.dom.Node sig = asse.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature").item(0);
asse.removeChild(sig);
asse2.appendChild(sig);